# Why doesn't my code compile?

Tags: c#

I am using regular expression in code behind file and defining string as

```
string ValEmail = "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*";

if (Regex.IsMatch(email, "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"))
{  }
else
{  }
```

It gives me warning and does not compile. How can I define such string combination?.

Comment: Please post the warning.

Comment: If you're getting an error: **post the error**. We are not psychic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# the backslash is a special character, if it is to represent a backslash we need to inform the compiler as such.

This can be achieved by escaping it with a backslash:

```
string ValEmail = "\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*";
```

Or using an `@` prefix when constructing the string:

```
string ValEmail = @"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*";
```

Comment: Never encountered this case before Now will remember for rest of my life. Thanks for quick replay and clear explanation. I will mark your answer correct as you first answer this question. Thanks to other guys who also replied with answer.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash is the escape char in c# strings. Technically you have to escape the backslash with another blackslash (`"\\"`) or just add an `@` before your string:

```
string ValEmail = @"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"` so the backslashes will get escaped